# Write a driver program implementing an ArrayList of CD objects

Tags: arraylist, wrapper, instance-variables

I have written the `CDException` class and the CD class, and now I'm trying to write a driver class to run the other classes. I have to

- Read the artist name from user
- Read the album name from user
- Read the price from user
- Read how many in stock from user

And print what they wrote but only the valid entries. Other entries will be ignored upon printing if they just enter blanks.

CD class:

```
import java.text.*;
public class CD {

private String sArtist;
private String sAlbum;
private double dPrice = 0;
private int inStock = 0;
String decimalFormats = "$##.##";   

    public CD(String sArtist, String sAlbum, double dPrice, int inStock) throws Exception{//constructors

        this.setArtist(sArtist);
        this.setAlbum(sAlbum);
        this.setPrice(dPrice);
        this.setinStock(inStock);
    }
        public String toString( ){//to string method

            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(decimalFormats);   //Formats the price
            String s = "Album: " + sAlbum + "\nArtist: " + sArtist +
                "\nPrice: " + df.format(dPrice);

            if(inStock == 0)
                return "Album: " + sAlbum + "\nArtist: " + sArtist +
                "\nPrice: $" + dPrice + "\nNot in Stock"; 
            else
                return s + "\nCurrently " + inStock + " in stock";
        }

        //mutator methods
        public void setArtist(String newArtist)throws Exception{
            if(newArtist.length( ) == 0){
                CDException cde = new CDException( );
                cde.setMessage("Artist name contains no characters" + "\nCannot create CD");
                throw cde;
            }
            else{
                this.sArtist = newArtist;
            }
        }
        public void setAlbum(String newAlbum) throws Exception{
            if(newAlbum.length( ) == 0){
                CDException cde = new CDException( );
                cde.setMessage("Album name contains no characters" + "\nCannot create CD");
                throw cde;
            }
            else{
                this.sAlbum = newAlbum;
            }
        }
        public void setPrice(double newPrice)throws Exception{
            if(newPrice < 0){
                CDException cde = new CDException( );
                cde.setMessage("CD Price cannot be negative" + "\nCannot create CD");
                throw cde;
            }
            else{
                this.dPrice = newPrice;
            }
        }
        public void setinStock(int newInStock)throws Exception{
            if(newInStock < 0){
                CDException cde = new CDException( );
                cde.setMessage("In stock cannot be negative" + "\nCannot create CD");
                throw cde;
            }
            else{
                this.inStock = newInStock;
            }
        }



        public String getsArtist( ){
            return this.sArtist;
        }
        public String getsAlbum( ){
            return this.sAlbum;
        }
        public double getdPrice( ){
            return this.dPrice;
        }
        public int getinStock( ){
            return this.inStock;
        }

    }   
}
```

And this is for my `CDException` class

```
public class CDException extends Exception {

   private String message = "Cannot create CD";

   public CDException( ){

   }
   public String getMessage( ){
    return this.message;
   }
   public void setMessage (String message){
    this.message = message;
   }
 }
```

And this is what I have so far for my driver class, but I need to modify it to that I can ask and read from the user the Artist name, Album title, Price for CD, and how many in stock and add it to an `ArrayList`, but first of course wrapping then adding to `ArrayList`.

```
 public class CDStore2{

  public static void main (String[ ] arg) throws Exception{

   ArrayList (CD) CD = new ArrayList( );

   try{
         CD cd1 = new CD("Muse", "The Resistance", 11.99, 20);
         System.out.println(cd1.toString( ));
         System.out.println("=========================");
   }
   catch(CDException cde){
        System.out.println(cde.getMessage( ));
        System.out.println("=========================");
   }

  try{
       CD cd2 = new CD("Yanni", "The Live at the Acropolis", 11.99, 0);
       System.out.println(cd2.toString( ));
       System.out.println("=========================");
   }
  catch(CDException cde){
      System.out.println(cde.getMessage( ));
      System.out.println("=========================");
  }


  try{
       CD cd3 = new CD("Muse", "Black Holes and Revelations", 10.99, 15);
       System.out.println(cd3.toString( ));
       System.out.println("=========================");
   }
  catch(CDException cde){
       System.out.println(cde.getMessage( ));
       System.out.println("=========================");
 }

 try{ 
      CD cd4 = new CD("Paul Mc Cartney", "All the Best", -0.99, 12);
      System.out.println(cd4.toString( ));  
      System.out.println("=========================");
   }
 catch(CDException cde){
      System.out.println(cde.getMessage( ));
      System.out.println("=========================");
  }

  try{
      CD cd5 = new CD("Lady Gaga", "The Fame Monster", 14.99, 44);
      System.out.println(cd5.toString( ));
      System.out.println("=========================");
   }
  catch(CDException cde){
      System.out.println(cde.getMessage( ));
      System.out.println("=========================");
  }    



  try{
      CD cd6 = new CD("", "California Gurls", 1.29, 4);
      System.out.println(cd6.toString( ));
      System.out.println("=========================");
   }
  catch(CDException cde){
      System.out.println(cde.getMessage( ));
      System.out.println("=========================");
  }    

try{   
      CD cd7 = new CD("Pitbull", "", 11.99, 12);
      System.out.println(cd7.toString( ));
      System.out.println("=========================");
   }
 catch(CDException cde){
      System.out.println(cde.getMessage( ));
      System.out.println("=========================");
   }    

  }//main method ends

 } //program ends
```

How do I, and where do I, write asking the user to enter the title, album, price and how many in stock? Do I write that in the CD class or in the driver class? And how would I write it in there using `ArrayLists`?

Comment: Holy wall of code! In order to receive better help and answers, you should trim down your question to the relevant parts only (rather than copy/pasting your whole code). Take a look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for tips on how to make the question better.

Comment: My apologies, I am very new to java. Please bear with me as I may seem like I dont know what I'm doing or talking about.

Comment: That's not a problem, Jamie. Just try your best to improve your question according to the guidelines on that link, and you should have better chances of someone helping.